# Setting color limits for basemap's pcolormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to set the color limits in a basemap pcolormesh, in the same way that

```
matplotlib.pyplot.clim(-1, 1)
```

would set the colour minimum to -1 and maximum to 1. My code looks like this:

```
llcrnrlat = numpy.amin(gridLatLon['lat'])-0.5
urcrnrlat = numpy.amax(gridLatLon['lat'])+0.5
llcrnrlon = numpy.amin(gridLatLon['lon'])-0.5
urcrnrlon = numpy.amax(gridLatLon['lon'])+0.5

m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlat=llcrnrlat,urcrnrlat=urcrnrlat,\
        llcrnrlon=llcrnrlon,urcrnrlon=urcrnrlon,resolution='c')

y, x = m(gridLatLon['lat'], gridLatLon['lon'])

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.pcolormesh(x, y, efdata, latlon=True)
```

and it produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZUb7.png), whereas I'm looking for the colours to be between -1 and 1, which would produce something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8DgK.png) (which I did using clim() but isn't on basemap).

Any and all suggestions as to how to improve my code are welcome.

Edit : `gridLatLon` is a dictionary containing one field called `lat`, which is a 2D numpy array of latitudes, and one field called `lon`, a 2D numpy array of corresponding longitudes. I'm trying to plot `efdata`, another 2D numpy array of the same size as the others.

Answer (score 3):

As per [`matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html)

```
m.pcolormesh(x, y, efdata, latlon=True, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
```